# Day Name From NSDate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I would like to show the name of day in my iPhone application and i don't found the solution.
Thanks for help

Answer (score 118, accepted):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
NSString *dayName = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:yourDate];
[dateFormatter release];
```

You get `dayName` in the locale of the user.

(check [Unicode standards](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns) for date formats samples)

Comment: FYI different versions of iOS/macOS use different versions of the Unicode standard; I found an older table of them at https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html

Comment: I am getting an abreviation with this: "Thu"

Answer (score 15):

I found it, the answer was :

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:now]);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Look at -[NSCalendar components:fromDate:].

A date by itself doesn't have a day, because it may have different days in different calendars (Gregorian, Chinese, etc.).

EDIT: actually, sorry.  That's what you would do to get the day and work with it programmatically. If you only want to display the day, look at NSDateFormatter.

Answer (score 3):

NSDate category

```
+ (NSString *)dayNameWith0Monday:(NSInteger)index {

    static NSDateFormatter * DateFormatter = nil;
    if (DateFormatter == nil) {
        DateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [DateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
        [DateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
    }

    NSDate * day = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:((4 * 24 * 60 * 60) + (24 * 60 * 60 * index))];
    return [DateFormatter stringFromDate:day];
}
```

0 will always be Monday! in case you need such behaviour

Comment: am I missing something or there is no way for DateFormatter to be != nil in a class method?

Comment: you can possibly omit the DateFormatter = nil;

Answer (score 1):

@Jilouc answer in **Swift:**

```
let formatter = DateFormatter.init()
formatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
let date = Date.init() //or any date
let dayName = formatter.string(from: date)
```

Answer (score 0):

There a many great resources for date and time processing - this is one I've learnt from over on [github](https://github.com/billymeltdown/nsdate-helper).