# day from current date in objective-c iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get the day of the week in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269093/how-do-i-get-the-day-of-the-week-in-objective-c)

I searched for many solutions on websites but i was unable to find it. For a particular problem I need to know what is the current day of week.In other words I need to know how to know whether it is sunday, monday, tuesday or so on.

Comment: Did you try to search for answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269093/how-do-i-get-the-day-of-the-week-in-objective-c

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar

the first day of the Gregorian calendar, Friday, 15 October 1582 (the cycle of weekdays was not affected).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSCalendar* cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents* comp = [cal components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"weekday - %d", [comp weekday]); // 1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday, etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Try this:

  NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
  NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:now]);
```

See this link too
     [Day Name From NSDate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745110/day-name-from-nsdate?rq=1)