# Get the Day from the date in iOS sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

In my app, want to get the day (i.e. `Sunday`, `Monday`,etc.) from the date.

My code is as follow:

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    //ask for current week
    NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    comps=[calendar components:NSWeekCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:currentDate];
    //create date on week start
    NSDate* weekstart=[calendar dateFromComponents:comps];

    //add 7 days
    NSMutableArray* week=[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:7];
    for (int i=1; i<=7; i++) {
        NSDateComponents *compsToAdd = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
        compsToAdd.day=i;
        NSDate *nextDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:compsToAdd toDate:weekstart options:0];
        NSLog(@"%@",nextDate);  // date is 2013-06-30 18:30:00 +0000



        NSDateFormatter *myFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [myFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"]; // day, like "Saturday"
        //[myFormatter setDateFormat:@"c"]; // day number, like 7 for saturday

        NSString *dayOfWeek = [myFormatter stringFromDate:nextDate];
```

**PROBLEM**

```
        NSLog(@"Today is: %@", dayOfWeek);  // Prints Mondays instead of Sunday
    }
```

**How can I solve this?**

Comment: Is a consistent locale / time zone applied throughout your source data and calculations?

Comment: Have you figured out what was wrong? How did you resolve this? I am having the same issue..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the day of the week with Cocoa Touch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269093/how-do-i-get-the-day-of-the-week-with-cocoa-touch)

Answer (score 6):

Try this :

```
    NSCalendar* calender = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents* component = [calender components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    return [component weekday]; // 1 for Sunday, 2 for Monday, and so on...
```

and see also this [Day Name From NSDate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745110/day-name-from-nsdate)  and this https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1700102?start=0&tstart=0

**Edit**

try this

```
NSString * time = @"2013-06-30T11:00:26+0100";

NSDateFormatter *df = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
NSDate *date1 = [df dateFromString:time];
long lgTime = (long)[date1 timeIntervalSince1970];
NSLog(@"%ld", lgTime);


NSCalendar* calender = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents* component = [calender components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:date1];

NSLog(@"date=%@ === %@",[NSDate date],date1);
NSLog(@"day= %d",[component weekday]); ///it return 1
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.. but it returns `2` instead of `1`

Comment: As you see in my sue. i passed date date is 2013-06-30 18:30:00 +0000.

Comment: As you see in my code. I passed date is 2013-06-30 18:30:00 +00000.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But still it returns `2`. There no 'T' included in my date.

Comment: it is one of the format, just try with manually if it is work then convert your date in that format.

Answer (score 6):

```
 NSCalendar* calender = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

 NSDateComponents* component = [calender components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

int weekDay = [component weekday];

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSString *weekdayString = [[formatter weekdaySymbols] objectAtIndex:weekDay - 1];

NSLog(@"Day ::: %@", weekdayString);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
NSDateFormatter* theDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[theDateFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
[theDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
NSString *weekDay =  [theDateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made a small `NSDate` category that helps you find the weekday name from a date.
It returns the localised string for the names of the weekdays.
Have a look at it. You can use it if you want to.

[NKLocalizedWeekday+NSDate](https://github.com/NikolaKirev/NKLocalizedWeekday)

Basically, this is the code you need:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
int weekdayNumber = [components weekday];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSString *weekdayString = [[formatter weekdaySymbols] objectAtIndex:weekdayNumber - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mydate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dt2 = [ [NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dt2 setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];

NSString *day = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[dt2 stringFromDate:mydate]];
```

Answer (score 0):

you face problem because it take local time zone

try this

```
  NSDateFormatter *dateformate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] ;
 [dateformate setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Australia/Sydney"]];
 [dateformate setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
  NSLog(@"%@", [dateformate stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
  NSLog(@"%@", [NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames]);
```

set time zone that you required.it may work and help you.

similar problem in [NSCalendar first day of week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106943/nscalendar-first-day-of-week) link refer it.also may help you.

Answer (score 0):

i am using this and it worked for me in iOS 8.4

```
-(NSString *) extractDayFromDate {
     NSCalendar* calender = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
     NSDateComponents* component = [calender components:NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:[NSDate date]];
     return [[calender weekdaySymbols] objectAtIndex:([component weekday]-1)]; 
}
```