# Get the Week Number in iOS SDK

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

I want to get the Week number of the year from the date.I tried the code as follow but gives me a wrong week number.

My code for week number:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2012-09-15"];


    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    NSLog(@"week: %i", [[calendar components: NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit fromDate:date] weekOfYear]); //Display 38 instead of 37
}
```

**Note:** If i try with with `[NSDate date]` display the correct.

Help me to solve this.. 
Thank you,

Comment: see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17403761/get-the-day-from-the-date-in-ios-sdk/17403855#17403855

Comment: There are different definitions for the week number of a date. I think that's the most likely cause of your problem. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendar_week#Week_numbering for details.

Comment: @SAMIRRATHOD,Thanks for reply... it just shows about the week day not for the week number .

Answer (score 20, accepted):

ObjectiveC:

```
 NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
 NSDateComponents *dateComponent = [calendar components:(NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
 NSLog(@"%@",dateComponent);
```

*Update*

```
 NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *dateComponent = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear | NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear) fromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"%@",dateComponent);
```

Swift:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let dateComponent = calendar.components([.WeekOfYear, .Day, .Month, .Year], fromDate: NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0))
print("weekOfYear \(dateComponent.weekOfYear)")
```

Swift 3 - Swift 5:

```
let component = Calendar.current.component(.weekOfYear, from: Date())
print("Week of Year \(component)")
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.. But when i try to give the date from String as seen above, it returns the wrong week number.

Answer (score 11):

`[NSCalendar currentCalendar]` gives you a Gregorian Calendar as default. You can use

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSISO8601Calendar];
```

to get an ISO 08601 conform calendar, which has week number **37** for your date.

Comment: sorry but for the `2012-09-25`, it returns _38 instead of 39_. **What's going wrong now?**

Comment: try to set the first week day of the calendar to the correct value (I don't know which ..) with - (void)setFirstWeekday:(NSUInteger)weekday

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3:
You need know last `Date` of selected month. Than check number of week for this week, and this will be your number of weeks in month

```
return Calendar.current.component(.weekOfMonth, from: lastDate ?? Date())
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated code in ObjectiveC used Xcode version - 9.1 - :

```
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *dateComponent = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear | NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)[dateComponent weekOfYear]);
```