# How to find that current date is from a Odd or Even week in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have to validate, questions on the basis of the odd or even week. If there is odd week then I will have to show different questions from even week. I am getting the questions from server from a "GET" method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the Week Number in iOS SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587697/get-the-week-number-in-ios-sdk)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
 NSDateComponents *dateComponent = [calendar components:(NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
 NSLog(@"%lu",(long unsigned)dateComponent.weekOfYear);

bool isEven = (dateComponent.weekOfYear % 2) == 0
```

Comment: `BOOL isEven = (dateComponent.weekOfYear & 1) == 0;`.  Original code from this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17587863/299924).  Note: your code will crash.

Comment: Do you know what `NSLog(@"%@", ...)` does?